# TCP packets sent in a particular sequence are not received accordingly

Tags: qt6

For an online game I connect multiple clients to a server. And the sequence of messages is crucial to comply with the game logic. For example, to start a new game I want all clients to agree first.

Problem is that my messages go through, but I don't receive it in the right sequence (the sender is also receiver).

```
class network : public QTcpSocket

void network::doSend(const MessageType msgType, QString msgReceiver, QString msgText) {
    ...
    if( this->write( msgText.toUtf8() ) != msgText.toUtf8().length() )
        qWarning() << "Not all data have been sent";
    this->waitForBytesWritten(5000);
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "sent" << QVariant::fromValue(msgType).toString() << "from" <<     m_sName;
#endif
}

void network::doReadyRead() {
    ...
    case nwSyncNewGame: emit onSyncNewGame(aLastMessage); break;
    ...
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    qDebug() << "received" << aLastMessage["MessageType"].toString() << "from" << aLastMessage["Sender"].toString();
#endif
}
```

Both messages to send and received are handled in the main thread. Like:

```
QObject::connect(m_pNetwork, SIGNAL(onSyncNewGame(QVariantMap)),
                 this, SLOT(doNetworkSyncNewGame(QVariantMap)));

void GamePlay::syncNewGame(QVariantMap aConfig) {
    m_pNetwork->doSend(network::nwPoll, "group", "");
    ...
    m_pNetwork->doSend(network::nwSyncNewGame, "group", configData.join("\a"));

void GamePlay::doNetworkSyncNewGame(QVariantMap aMsg) {
    emit applyConfig(aMsg);
    emit newGame(aMsg["IsLoading"].toBool());
}
```

```
sent "nwPoll" from "Scotty"
sent "nwSyncNewGame" from "Scotty"
sent "nwAnswer" from "Scotty"
received "nwSyncNewGame" from "Scotty"
received "nwRefresh" from "Scotty"
received "nwPoll" from "Scotty"
```

Where shall I look for a solution?

Comment: Can you print the entire packets, in particular the timestamps?

Comment: * sent 1660546441960 "nwPoll" from "Scotty"
* sent 1660546441961 "nwSyncNewGame" from "Scotty"
* sent 1660546441994 "nwAnswer" from "Scotty"
* received 1660546442055 "nwInformation" from "Server"
* received 1660546442103 "nwRefresh" from "Scotty"
* received 1660546442232 "nwPoll" from "Scotty"
(Not all messages passed through in this case for some reason, I receive nwSyncNewGame after any other message.)

Full project at https://github.com/Scrabble3D/4.0

Answer (score 0):

Sent more than one package from a function in the main thread to the socket which ended in a buffer. Restructured the code and everything is fine now. Plenty of questions about immediately sending packages are handled in different topics.